# ANGULAR 2: How i can get the Values of that Array?

Tags: angular

Right Now I'm try to get the value of this array [ScreenShot](http://prntscr.com/j97yie)

I'm try to get that Value with

```
var L = e.Lookups
```

or

```
var L = e['Lookups']
```

But always that object return undefined when I'm trying to get that array.

Any Suggestions?

And thanks for the help.

Update:

[Screenshot 2](http://prntscr.com/j97yie)

Code: 
In this method I receive an array of objects,
Access directly to position 5 in debug mode, and there comes the undefined value

```
getQuestions(template: any) {
console.log('template: ', template)
console.log('1-template 5: ', template[5].Lookups);
console.log('2-template 5: ', template[5]['Lookups']);
var questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];

if(template !== undefined && template !== null) {
  template.forEach(e => {

      // Getting Lookups
      switch(e.SimpleDataType){
        case 'Number':
              questions.push(
                new TextboxQuestion({
                  Field: e.Field,
                  Label: e.Label,
                  Required: e.Required,
                  type: e.SimpleDataType,
                  ACL: e.ACL,
                  value: e.value  || ''
                })
              );
        break;

        case 'Int':
              questions.push(
                new TextboxQuestion({
                  Field: e.Field,
                  Label: e.Label,
                  Required: e.Required,
                  type: 'Number',
                  ACL: e.ACL,
                  value: e.value  || ''
                })
              );
        break;

        case 'String':
              questions.push(
                new TextboxQuestion({
                  Field: e.Field,
                  Label: e.Label,
                  Required: e.Required,
                  Hidden : e.Hidden,
                  SimpleDataType: 'String',
                  ACL: e.ACL,
                  value: e.value  || ''
                })
              );
        break;

        case 'Character':
              questions.push(
                new TextboxQuestion({
                  Field: e.Field,
                  Label: e.Label,
                  Required: e.Required,
                  Hidden : e.Hidden,
                  SimpleDataType: 'String',
                  type: 'String',
                  ACL: e.ACL,
                  value: e.value  || ''
                })
              );
        break;
        case 'String List, Single':
              questions.push(
                new DropdownQuestion({
                  Field: e.Field,
                  Label: e.Label,
                  Required: e.Required,
                  Hidden : e.Hidden,
                  type: 'String List, Single',
                  SimpleDataType: 'List',
                  options: e.Lookups,
                  ACL: e.ACL,
                  value: e.value || ''
              }));
        break;

        case 'String List, Multi':
          let v = [ ];
          v.push(e.value);
              questions.push(
                new DropdownQuestion({
                  Field: e.Field,
                  Label: e.Label,
                  Required: e.Required,
                  Hidden : e.Hidden,
                  type: 'String List, Multi',
                  SimpleDataType: 'List',
                  options: e.Lookups,
                  ACL: e.ACL,
                  value: v || []
              }));
        break;

        case 'Boolean':
              questions.push(
                new CheckboxControl({
                  Field: e.Field,
                  Label: e.Label,
                  type: 'Boolean',
                  Required: e.Required,
                  Hidden : e.Hidden,
                  ACL: e.ACL,
                  value: e.value
                })
              );

        break;

        case 'Date':
              questions.push(
                new DateQuestion({
                  Field: e.Field,
                  Label: e.Label,
                  type: 'Date',
                  Required: e.Required,
                  Hidden : e.Hidden,
                  SimpleDataType: 'Date',
                  ACL: e.ACL,
                  value: e.value  || ''
                })
              );
        break;


        case 'Timestamp':
          questions.push(
            new DateQuestion({
              Field: e.Field,
              Label: e.Label,
              type: 'Date',
              Required: e.Required,
              Hidden : e.Hidden,
              SimpleDataType: 'Date',
              ACL: e.ACL,
              value: e.value || ''
            })
          );
          break;
      }

    });
    // Field input type=File
          questions.push(
            new FileQuestion({
              Field: "File",
              Label: "Upload Image",
              Required: false,
              type: "file",
              ACL: 1
            })
          );
    return questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post more code pls

Comment: Both should be working. Can you show the entire method where you're trying to access 'e'

Comment: yes sirs, i made a update: @DZDomi

Comment: yes sirs, i made a update: @Everett

Comment: That was a simple example to find another way to get that values of this array in the object.

Comment: well you are iterating over template.. with `e=>,,,` so you cant asign `let L = e.lookups` because e is the iterator, in those case `L = template`, or on each iteraction you must `L.push(e);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getQuestions(template: any) {
  template = [...template];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, i try that, but i still have the same result.